# Setting scenes in AndEngine with some Effects

Tags: android, andengine

I am using a scene manager with ten scenes with only one engine.
All i want to do is that whenever I switch between scenes there should be an effect. Like when I switch from scene1 to scene2, scene2 should come something like revolving or zooming on or fliping etc. Is this possible if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scenes extend Entity, so you can use some EntityModifiers to transition between scenes. There are some limits since both the incoming and outgoing scenes can't be active at the same time.

Here's an example that might get you headed in the right direction - I used something similar to transition between my splashScene and mainScene

```
outgoingScene.registerEntityModifier(new ScaleModifier(3f, 1f, 0f, new IEntityModifierListener() {

   @Override
   public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
       mEngine.setScene(incomingScene);
   } }));
```

Comment: giving it a try lets see what will happen. I got the main idea.

Comment: but how can I do this on click of a button ??